# How to correctly adjust prices using economic indexes?

Tags: inflation, price-index

I need to develop a readjustment index for a set of costs of a given company/product. However, overall price indexes such as CPI do not fit well the expenses.

For example: suppose I have three categories of expenses, Labor, Rent and Building Material in which these categories have the following weights:

$$
Overall cost = 0,40*Labor + 0,35*Rent + 0,25*Building Material
$$

I can't use a single index (such as CPI) to readjust these expenses as each category behave very differently from the CPI. How would you develop a pricing equation that best readjusts the costs?

What I have tried so far: regress individual categories against several price indexes for over 5 years of both monthly and accumulated 12-month periods. The idea is to use the series that have economic reasoning and higher values of R-squared. Using accumulated 12-month periods would reduce the problem of seasonality. My expenses are not adjusted for seasonality whereas the price indexes are. As the cost adjustment mechanism should be easy, I'm trying simpler solutions (using an econometric filter to seasonality and propose complicated econometrics would confuse the management).